# How to update the price of a hosted paypal button using Button Manager API?

Tags: php, button, paypal, shopping-cart

I'm really new at PayPal and I've been trudging through the PayPal website but while it has volumes of references they don't seem to be accompanies with simple snippets of code in a fully working background template, and I've spent days trying out some of their stuff to no avail! I know how to add buttons via the PayPal merchant account, but that isn't enough.

**What I need to do is simply update the "amount" variable of a hosted PayPal button dynamically.** That is all. This button is used by customers to upload an aggregate shopping cart, which was custom made by me in PHP. It's not an existing third party shopping cart.

1- Do I need to change its `cmd` from "_s-xclick" to "_cart"? Why can't I just dynamically set the price of the button based on the current cart's total?

2- Most importantly, regardless of the above, how do I dynamically set the price of a button anyway?  I am trying to use the ButtonManager API to dynamically change a button I created through my PayPal seller account. I thought I was on to something with this link: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/BM/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview#id093PD0M07HS but now it needs the Third Party's Username for the API. I don't have a third party username because I made this simple cart myself. Where do I go? This so complicated and I'm really short on time! I am not going to be using IPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using wanting to change the amount of a hosted button, it has to be done 1 of 2 ways.  Either you would have to log into the account that the button was created on and adjust the amount from within the account.  The 2 second option would be to use the BMUpdateButton API to update the button amount via using an API.  However, to be able to update the button, you would either need the API credentials of the PayPal account that the button was created from or you would need to have the account holder of that account grant your API 3rd party permissions to be able to execute API calls on their account.

There is a list of the available variables that can be passed over with this API [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/bmupdatebutton-api-operation-nvp) that may be useful to you as well.  As far as code goes, you could look at the DoDirectPayment examples [here](https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-dodirectpayment-php-5.3/nvp).  It's not an example for the same API call that you would be using, but you would just need to mofidy the code to pass over the different variables and values.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: THANK you! I've been running around in a labyrinth of the developer pages and the API references but the DoDirectPayment block of code is finally putting things together!